# SetDelayed error for Derivative rule

Tags: assignment

Having a delayed assignment of the form

```
Derivative[1][f][x_] := HoldForm[f[x]]
```

works. But if there is a delayed assignment for f as in

```
f[x_] := g[x]
Derivative[1][f][x_] := HoldForm[f[x]]
```

the error

```
SetDelayed::write: Tag Function in ((g^\[Prime])[#1]&)[x_] is Protected.
```

occurs. Why is `f[x]` evaluated despite `HoldForm` and how can I write a delayed assignment of this form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) has a built-in definition that applies whenever `f` gets a [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues). For example, suppose you define:

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

Then, `` f` ``, or in FullForm, `Derivative[1][f]` already has a definition:

```
Derivative[1][f]
```

> 2 #1 &

which, as you can see, is a pure function. So, trying to define:

```
Derivative[1][f][x_] := rhs
```

is equivalent to doing:

```
(2 #1 &)[x_] := rhs
```

and this is why you get an error, since it is not possible to define a definition for the protected symbol [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function). If you want to overwrite the default derivative of a function, you need to use:

```
Derivative[1][f] = g;
```

Then:

```
f'[x]
```

> g[x]